# Kubernetes Traefik v2.3.0 - Web UI 404 Not Found after removing --api.insecure

Tags: user-interface, authentication, kubernetes, http-status-code-404, traefik

I'm running Traefik v2.3.0 in a AKS (Azure Kubernetes Service) Cluster and i'm currently trying to setup a Basic Authentication on my Traefik UI.

The dashboard (Traefik UI) works fine without any authentication but i'm getting the server not found page when I try to access with a Basic Authentication.

Here is my configuration.

IngressRoute, Middleware for BasicAuth, Secret and Service :

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: traefik-ui
  namespace: ingress-basic
spec:
  entryPoints:
  - websecure
  routes:
  - kind: Rule
    match: Host(`traefik-ui.domain.com`) && PathPrefix(`/`) || PathPrefix(`/dashboard`)
    services:
    - name: traefik-ui
      port: 80
    middlewares:
    - name: traefik-ui-auth
      namespace: ingress-basic
  tls:
    secretName: traefik-ui-cert
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: traefik-secret
  namespace: ingress-basic
data:
  users: |2
    dWlhZG06JGFwcjEkanJMZGtEb1okaS9BckJmZzFMVkNIMW80bGtKWFN6LwoK
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: traefik-ui-auth
  namespace: ingress-basic
spec:
  basicAuth:
    secret: traefik-secret
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik-ui
  namespace: ingress-basic
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: traefik-ingress-lb
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

DaemonSet and Service:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress
  namespace: ingress-basic
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: traefik-ingress-lb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: traefik-ingress-lb
        name: traefik-ingress-lb
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: size
                operator: In
                values:
                - small
      containers:
      - args:
        - --api.dashboard=true
        - --accesslog
        - --accesslog.fields.defaultmode=keep
        - --accesslog.fields.headers.defaultmode=keep
        - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
        - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
        - --entrypoints.metrics.address=:8082
        - --providers.kubernetesIngress.ingressClass=traefik-cert-manager
        - --certificatesresolvers.default.acme.email=info@domain.com
        - --certificatesresolvers.default.acme.storage=acme.json
        - --certificatesresolvers.default.acme.tlschallenge
        - --providers.kubernetescrd
        - --ping=true
        - --pilot.token=xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xx
        - --metrics.statsd=true
        - --metrics.statsd.address=localhost:8125
        - --metrics.statsd.addEntryPointsLabels=true
        - --metrics.statsd.addServicesLabels=true
        image: traefik:v2.3.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: traefik-ingress-lb
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: web
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: admin
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 443
          name: websecure
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /acme/acme.json
          name: acme
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      serviceAccount: traefik-ingress
      serviceAccountName: traefik-ingress
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      tolerations:
      - effect: NoSchedule
        key: size
        operator: Equal
        value: small
      volumes:
      - hostPath:
          path: /srv/configs/acme.json
          type: ""
        name: acme
```

With this configuration :
kubectl exec -it -n ingress-basic traefik-ingress-2m88q -- curl http://localhost:8080/dashboard/

```
404 page not found
```

When removing the Middleware and adding "--api.insecure" in the DaemonSet config :
kubectl exec -it -n ingress-basic traefik-ingress-1hf4q -- curl http://localhost:8080/dashboard/

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Traefik</title><meta charset=utf-8><meta name=description content="Traefik UI"><meta name=format-detection content="telephone=no"><meta name=msapplication-tap-highlight content=no><meta name=viewport content="user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,width=device-width"><link rel=icon type=image/png href=statics/app-logo-128x128.png><link rel=icon type=image/png sizes=16x16 href=statics/icons/favicon-16x16.png><link rel=icon[...]</body></html>
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here? Is there any other way of doing it ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another take on the IngressRoute, adapted to your environment.

I think 99% of the issue is actual route matching, especially if you say `--api.insecure` works.
Also as a rule of a thumb, logging & access log would help a lot in the DaemonSet definition.

```
    - --log
    - --log.level=DEBUG
    - --accesslog
```

```
    ---
    apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
    kind: IngressRoute
    metadata:
      name: traefik-ui
      namespace: ingress-basic
    spec:
      entryPoints:
        - websecure
      routes:
      - match: Host(`traefik-ui.domain.com`) && (PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/dashboard`))
        kind: Rule
        services:
        - name: api@internal
          kind: TraefikService
        middlewares:
          - name: traefik-basic-auth
      tls:
        secretName: traefik-ui-cert
```

Comment: Hello DarthHTTP, thank you for your reply. Indeed debugging by adding more logs helped me to figure out the issue. You were right about the routing rules. Here is my config which works now when accessing "https://traefik-ui.domain.com :
[...]
  routes:
  - kind: Rule
    match: Host(`traefik-ui.domain.com`) && PathPrefix(`/`)
    middlewares:
    - name: traefik-ui-auth
      namespace: ingress-basic
    services:
    - kind: TraefikService
      name: api@internal
  tls:
    secretName: traefik-ui-cert

Comment: You're welcome, @ThibThib. Make sure you include the /api path too. :)